# if there is an exception in Onmessage() method , whether it will retain the messgae in the Queue and invoke MDB again at a later point

Tags: java, jms, weblogic12c

I am using Oracle Weblogic Server,How to handle the exception in mdb onMessage().If there is an exception then message will be retained in the queue or not ,Because the message is not processed & is it possible to get the message later

Here is my code:

```
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;

@MessageDriven(
activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") ,
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="connectionFactoryJndiName",propertyValue="TestQCF"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationJndiName", propertyValue="testQ")
}
,mappedName="testQ"
)

public class MyMDB implements MessageListener{
public void onMessage(Message message){

    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
    try {
        System.out.println("Received message is :"+ textMessage.getText());

    }
    catch (JMSException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If there is an exception then message will be retained in the queue or not ,Because the message is not processed & is it possible to get the message later

That depends on the transaction attribute specified for the MDB. MDBs are invoked by the container and when the transaction_type is set to CONTAINER, only two transaction types - REQUIRED or NOT_SUPPORTED can be specified with the default being the latter.

When the transaction type is set to REQUIRED, an exception causes the transaction to rollback and when an MDB Container Managed Transaction is rolled back, the container redelivers the message.

You could also explicitly rollback the transaction on exceptions.

```
public void onMessage(Message m){
     try{
          if(m.getJMSRedelivered()){
             //do whatever for redelivery cases
           }
     //do other stuff
     }catch(Exception e){
          //log
          msgContext.setRollbackOnly();
      }
}
```

I often go back to this resource http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html to understand message redelivery and transactions. It was published in 2002, but for me, its the best write up that explains JMS transactions and redelivery.

Comment: Do I need to add the setRollback() manually in my catch block??

Comment: No. Remember MDB cannot join a transaction, so all you have to do is throw an Exception from within the MDB to rollback the transaction.

Comment: Any links is highly appriciated

Comment: If I get exception in my onMessage() ,Can I push the message to Error Queue and would again send it back to the normal queue so that it can try to resend the same message again.

Comment: If the exception doesn't rollback the transaction, catch it and call messageContext.setRollbackOnly() in the catch block,

Comment: How do I come to know that my exception is rolledback or not??Can u add the code above

Comment: Please check above

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the error destination in case you need to retry on failure. This you can define in you xml file where you have defined your jms queues, connection factories, etc.

Here are references : 

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLACH/pagehelp/JMSjmsdestinationsjmsqueueredeliverytitle.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jmsqueue_config_redelivery.html

Comment: I am not using any xml file.Just deployed the war file on weblogic

Comment: Xml is just the configuration for JMS, you can add that configurations even in your code where you have added your other configurations for JMS.